# Appending to custom object array in swift

Tags: swift

I have an object array like this:

```
private var _allusers = [Int:User]()
```

Here User is a custom class. Now, I am calling a PHP file and populating the _allusers object array the first time without any problem. However, I am running into problems IF I try to insert something at the beginning of the _allusers object array.

Generally, this is possible.

```
private var _intarray = [Int]()
self._intarray.insert(myObject, atIndex:0)
```

If I try to do the same for the object array I have then it doesn’t work.

```
self._allusers.insert(myObject, atIndex:0)
```

It gives me an error stating insert is not a function.

Can someone please help me with this? How can I insert an element at the beginning of the existing object array?

Comment: For starters, `[Int:User]` defines a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `_allusers` is not array, it is `Dictionary` (unordered type). Depending from what you need, you can use array of tuples for example:

```
private var _allusers = [(Int, User)]() // this is array
```

Comment: Is there any way of inserting at the beginning of the dictionary since my dictionary index starts from 0 and increases sequentially?

Comment: Your question not have sense. Dictionary is unordered type. You can use array of tuples or of any else data structure if you wish.

Comment: @user3897036 Take a look at Collection Types in this Apple Document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Shadow Of is saying, in this case you seem to be stating that you want an array of Users indexed from 0 to N.  What you are currently defining is a dictionary which indexes Users with arbitrary indexes over the entire range of Int, so you could have gaps users[0], users[3], users[8] without having users[1] or users[2].  If you truly have consecutive indices, just change your declaration to declare an array instead of a dictionary.

```
private var _allusers = [User]()
```

Now, _allusers is an array, the Users are indexed from 0..

```
_allusers.insert(newUser, atIndex:0)
```